# How to write a batch file to crop all the pdfs in a directory and store them in a new directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf

I'm totally unfamiliar with batch files but I'm pretty sure I need one for the task at hand:

I want to run pdfcrop for all the files in a particular directory and store the cropped files in a new directory. New directory is called 'croppedfiles' and if it doesn't already exist in the location where the pdfs are stored then such a directory is created and the output files are stored there.

I'd like the output files to have the same name as old files with the addition of '_cpp' at the end.

syntax for pdfcrop is just pdfcrop input.pdf output.pdf

Comment: It sounds like a good requirements description. What's lacking now is the effort you've made to at least attempt something yourself. I'm sure that there are posts here under the batch-file tag that show how to run a command on each file in a directory that matches a specification, and also that copies files and renames them in the process. You can try searching for them using the `[batch-file] search phrase` syntax (including the `[]` around the tag) to help get you started. Then if you run into problems, you can post your effort and ask a specific question about that problem. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite I know the result will resemble this:
for /f %%f in ('dir /b c:\') do pdfcrop %%f But unfortunately I don't know what '/f' means or '%%f' so this was as far as I got

Comment: See [this MS TechNet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730909.aspx), and look at `for`, which explains what `/f` means and how to use it. (Or just type `for /?` or `help for` at a command prompt, but the web page is easier to navigate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the poor material you provided for this question - I mean only your `for` cycle quotation - I can only suggest a pair of tips: first you can narrow the group of files on which the `for` cycle is going to work, using a piped `find ".pdf"` command. Then you can use another nested `for` cycle to obtain the name of the file to be processed by `pdfcrop` and to set it as a variable to be used for the output path. Here is the example script:

> for /f "delims=" %%g in ('dir ^"[set your desired path]^" ^| find
>   ^".pdf^"') do (   set VAR=%%g     for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%m in
>   ('!VAR!') do (mkdir "[chose your subdirectory name]" pdfcrop "!VAR!" "[subdirectory]\%%m[set
>   your additional characters].%%n"  ) )

I hope it works, because I have been not able to test it.